# Пропал Status Bar (строка состояния) vscode, как её восстановить?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Пропала нижняя синяя панель (строка) на экране в vscode, теперь не знаю, как увидеть изменения произошедшие после изменений кода в браузере. Как восстановить эту панель?

Answer (score 2):

2 способа чтобы скрыть/показать строку состояния (Status Bar)

1. Через пользовательский интерфейс `View -> Apparence -> Status Bar`
2. Через `Command palette`

   - Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, или нажать <kbd>F1</kbd>
   - в строку ввести `toggle status bar`
   - нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>